# Alignment of table of contents (TOC)

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, overleaf

I want to center both **Chapter** and heading of chapter **Author's Declaration**. I am successful in my purpose as can be seen in LaTeX output. But the table of contents (TOC) is not align. Kindly suggest a simple solution to align the TOC.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\centering Chapter}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{ \centering Author's Declaration}

\chapter{\centering bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb}
\section{bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb1}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could "disable" `\centering` just during the production of the table of contents.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\centering Chapter}

\begin{document}

{\let\centering\relax\tableofcontents}

\chapter{\centering Author's Declaration}

\chapter{\centering bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb}
\section{bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb1}


\end{document}
```

Alternately, you could use the optional argument to `\chapter` to omit the `\centering` for the toc:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\centering Chapter}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter[Author's Declaration]{\centering Author's Declaration}

\chapter[bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb]{\centering bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb}
\section{bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb1}


\end{document}
```

In either case, the centering in the toc goes away

[image]

Comment: Your both suggestions work for this particular problem. Thank you.